# Redefining SCSS variables with data atributes

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i need to make this calculator have specific themes 3 to be exact. I read some documentation and found a good way to do it with data atributes. I goes as follows. You define all the variables for a specific theme but only activatie them when a certain data atribute is present in the html tag. If you change the data atribute the variables should now be redefined for that theme. Now ik know this works in CSS but it doesnt seam to work for SCSS. maybe i am doing something wrong syntax related.

these are my SCSS variables.

```
// Typography
$main-Font: 'Spartan',
sans-serif;

// Theme 1
$background: hsl(222, 26%, 31%);
$keypadColor: hsl(223, 31%, 20%);
$ScreenColor: hsl(224, 36%, 15%);

$tertiaryKeyColor: hsl(225, 21%, 49%);
$tertiaryKeyColorShadow: hsl(224, 28%, 35%);

$secondaryKeyColor: hsl(6, 63%, 50%);
$secondaryKeyColorShadow: hsl(6, 70%, 34%);

$basicKeyColor: hsl(30, 25%, 89%);
$basicKeyColorShadow: hsl(28, 16%, 65%);

$text1: hsl(221, 14%, 31%);
$text2: hsl(0, 0, 100%);
$text3: hsl(0, 0, 100%);


html[data-color-mode="theme-2"] {
  // Theme 2
  $background: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  $keypadColor: hsl(0, 5%, 81%);
  $ScreenColor: hsl(0, 0%, 93%);

  $tertiaryKeyColor: hsl(185, 42%, 37%);
  $tertiaryKeyColorShadow: hsl(185, 58%, 25%);

  $secondaryKeyColor: hsl(25, 98%, 40%);
  $secondaryKeyColorShadow: hsl(25, 99%, 27%);

  $basicKeyColor: hsl(45, 7%, 89%);
  $basicKeyColorShadow: hsl(35, 11%, 61%);

  $text1: hsl(60, 10%, 19%);
  $text2: hsl(0, 0, 100%);
  $text3: hsl(0, 0, 100%);
}

html[data-color-mode="theme-3"]{
  // Theme 3
  $background: hsl(268, 75%, 9%);
  $keypadColor: hsl(268, 71%, 12%);
  $ScreenColor: hsl(268, 71%, 12%);

  $tertiaryKeyColor: hsl(281, 89%, 26%);
  $tertiaryKeyColorShadow: hsl(285, 91%, 52%);

  $ScreenColor: hsl(176, 100%, 44%);
  $secondaryKeyColorShadow: hsl(177, 92%, 70%);

  $basicKeyColor: hsl(268, 47%, 21%);
  $basicKeyColorShadow: hsl(290, 70%, 36%);

  $text1: hsl(52, 100%, 62%);
  $text2: hsl(0, 0, 100%);
  $text3: hsl(198, 20%, 13%);
}
```

this is the HTML

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-color-mode="theme-1">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->
  
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Calculator app</title>

  <!-- stylesheet link -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">

  <!-- Js link -->
  <script src="./js/app.js" defer></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="calculator-container">

      <header class="flex">
        <h2>Calc</h2>
        <div class="toggle-button-container">
          <h3>theme</h3>
          <input type="range" max="2" value="0" name="theme-selector" id="theme-selector-button">
        </div>
      </header>

      <div class="display">

      </div>

      <main class="keypad grid">
        <button>7</button>
        <button>8</button>
        <button>9</button>
        <button class="tertiary-color">DEL</button>

        <button>4</button>
        <button>5</button>
        <button>6</button>
        <button>+</button>

        <button>1</button>
        <button>2</button>
        <button>3</button>
        <button>-</button>

        <button>.</button>
        <button>0</button>
        <button>/</button>
        <button>x</button>

        <button class="col-span tertiary-color">RESET</button>
        <button class="col-span secondary-color">=</button>
      </main>

    </div>

</body>
</html>

and this function changes the data atribute. Now this part works because i can see the atribute change in the dev tools

```
const themeSelectorBtn = document.getElementById('theme-selector-button');
let keypadBtns = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button'));
const display = document.querySelector('.display');
const app = document.querySelector('html')

themeSelectorBtn.addEventListener('input', () => {
  let currentValue = themeSelectorBtn.value;
  if(currentValue == 0){
    app.dataset.colorMode = 'theme-1';
  } else if(currentValue == 1) {
    app.dataset.colorMode = 'theme-2';
  } else {
    app.dataset.colorMode = 'theme-3';
  }
})
```
and the documentation i am trying to replicate contains this but in CSS instead of SCSS
```
:root {
    /* Theme 1 */
   /* Backgrounds */
   --main-bg-theme: hsl(222, 26%, 31%);
   --toggle-bg-theme: hsl(221, 38%, 25%);
   --btn-bg-theme: hsl(221, 35%, 19%);
   --screen-bg-theme: hsl(224, 36%, 15%);
   --top: white;

   /* Button */
   --btn-second-bg-theme: hsl(225, 21%, 49%);
   --btn-second-shadow-theme: hsl(223, 31%, 24%);
   --equals-theme: hsl(6, 63%, 50%);
   --btn-primary-bg-theme: hsl(30, 25%, 89%);
   --btn-primary-shadow-theme: hsl(28, 16%, 65%);

   /* Text */
   --text1-theme:  hsl(221, 14%, 31%);
   --text2-theme: hsl(0, 0, 100%);
   --equals: white;
   --display: hsl(0, 0, 100%);
   --equals-shadow:  hsl(6, 70%, 34%);

 }

 html[data-color-mode="theme2"] {
    /* Backgrounds */
   --main-bg-theme: hsl(0, 2%, 89%);
   --toggle-bg-theme: hsl(0, 12%, 82%);
   --btn-bg-theme: hsl(0, 12%, 82%);
   --screen-bg-theme: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
   --top: black;

   /* Button */
   --btn-second-bg-theme: hsl(185, 42%, 37%);
   --btn-second-shadow-theme: hsl(185, 50%, 25%);
   --equals-theme: hsl(6, 63%, 50%);
   --btn-primary-bg-theme: hsl(45, 7%, 89%);
   --btn-primary-shadow-theme: hsl(35, 11%, 61%);

   /* Text */
   --text1-theme:  hsl(192, 12%, 8%);
   --text2-theme: hsl(0, 0, 100%);
   --equals: white;
   --display: black;
   --equals-shadow:  hsl(6, 70%, 34%);
 }

 
 html[data-color-mode="theme3"] {
   /* Backgrounds */
   --main-bg-theme: hsl(268, 75%, 9%);
   --toggle-bg-theme: hsl(268, 74%, 20%);
   --btn-bg-theme: hsl(268, 74%, 20%);
   --screen-bg-theme: hsl(268, 74%, 20%);
   --top: hsl(54, 63%, 75%);

   /* Button */
   --btn-second-bg-theme: hsl(281, 89%, 26%);
   --btn-second-shadow-theme: hsl(290, 69%, 43%);
   --equals-theme: hsl(177, 92%, 70%);
   --btn-primary-bg-theme: hsl(281, 71%, 21%);
   --btn-primary-shadow-theme: hsl(290, 70%, 36%);

   /* Text */
   --text1-theme:  hsl(54, 63%, 75%);
   --text2-theme: hsl(0, 0, 100%);
   --equals: black;
   --display: hsl(54, 63%, 75%);
   --equals-shadow:  hsl(189, 69%, 43%);
}

```
````

Comment: This doesn't work because SCSS compiles to CSS and what you have in your SCSS doesn't compile to anything meaningful - those variables are not getting assigned to any property - variables in SCSS are used to assign values to properties of selectors. Your CSS that works is because you are changing **CSS** variable values.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out i made a silly mistake. I put a - in between colorMode in the HTML file. It works fine now.